# Text keeps flashing on animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a flashcard site to remember basics about Javascript. I am able to display the cards as they should, but as soon as I try to flip it the text disappears and then occasionally flashes on hover. Here is a screen capture of what happens: gyazo.com/150e7620beec06bb4acdb95c4cf4ba39
I've tried quite a few things, but I cant figure out why.

This is my css

```
body {
    background-color: #c8d0d2;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 1rem 2rem;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card-grid {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-color: white;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 150ms;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(var(--rotate-y, 0))
                          translateY(var(--translate-y, 0));
}

.card:hover {
    --translate-y: -2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.card.flip {
    --rotate-y: 180deg;
}

.card .front {
    left: 0;
}

.card .front,
.card .back {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1rem;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flashcard-options {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.flashcard-option {
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.flashcard-option:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

and here is my React code:

````
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function Flashcard({ flashcard }) {
    const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState("initial");

    const frontEl = useRef();
    const backEl = useRef();

    function setMaxHeight() {
        const frontHeight = frontEl.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        const backHeight = backEl.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        setHeight(Math.max(frontHeight, backHeight, 100));
    }
    
    useEffect(setMaxHeight, [flashcard.question, flashcard.answer]);
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", setMaxHeight);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", setMaxHeight);
    }, []);

    return (
    <div
      className={`card ${flip ? "flip" : ""}`}
      style={{ height: height }}
      onClick={() => setFlip(!flip)}
    >
      <div className="front" ref={frontEl}>
        <p>{flashcard.question}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="back" ref={backEl}>
        <p>{flashcard.answer}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```
````

Comment: As  you flip a card it will go in and out of being hovered so it will 'flash'

Comment: The problem is I can't even see the text, it should show the text like it does on the front of the card. It should just be the card that "flashes" when I hover, not the text inside of it.

Comment: It would be great if you could share a snippet.

Comment: Yes sure thing: https://gyazo.com/150e7620beec06bb4acdb95c4cf4ba39

Answer (score 0):

this is weird, I ran the code on my pc and it worked ok. after flipping everything seems to work fine, nothing flashed.

here is a link to the video (sorry for the bad quality): https://www.sendspace.com/file/40jvao

do you have more code you use that may affect it or is related to this component? try using `FlashCard` in empty project in order to test it by itself.